# What text to speech programs can I use to improve my listening skills?

Tags: discussion, resource-request, online-resources

Does anybody know any website (or app) to make text to speech?

I've found [Amazon Polly](https://aws.amazon.com/polly/), but I'd like to know if there's a better choice.

Comment: You might try searching over at softwarerecs.stackexchange.com and asking a question if you can't find any suitable answers. There are some tips for asking there on their meta site: http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/4677

Comment: Also, judging from their sample text, that site is not what I would recommend for a learner. There is definitely some robotic sounds for some sentences for most of the voices I tried. Audio books or radio shows with transcripts would be better.

Comment: @ColleenV I've just found the listenings of my books. It's the *Solutions* saga by Tim falla and Paul A. Davies.